# Removing LineSegments from Line?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to do a particular thing with three.js, and am having a hell of a time figuring out if I should just start this from the ground up or if I'm on the right track.

I'm parsing my way through a gcode file, which is essentially a giant text file full of position and extrusion data for 3D printers. I sequentially read through it and load all the positions into `THREE.Geometry()` as vertices, and I create a line using all of those positions and vertex colours.

Here's what it looks like:

```
var vis = new Visualizer();
vis.init();

if (typeof geometryArr == 'object' && geometryArr[0] != undefined) {
  colorScheme = [ "#0000ff", "#00ff00", "#d3d3d3", "#ff0000" ];

  var lastGeo = [0, 0, 0, false, 0];
  var currentGeo = [];

  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  var lineMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 1.0,
  });

  geometryArr.map(function(points, i) {
    currentGeo = points;

    if (currentGeo[3] == true && lastGeo[3] == true) {
      geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( currentGeo[0], currentGeo[1], currentGeo[2] ) );
      geometry.colors.push( new THREE.Color ( colorScheme[ currentGeo[4] ] ) );
      lastGeo = currentGeo;
    } else {
      lastGeo = currentGeo;
    }
  });

  line = new THREE.Line( geometry, lineMat, THREE.LineSegments );

  vis.scene.add(line);
}

vis.render();
vis.animate();
```

Basically, I know which pairs of vertices should be invisible (`geometryArr` has a flag for this sort of thing), so I know which ones I need to take care of.

What I have tried:
* Removing the offending vertice pairs - the line is simply drawn between the next set of vertices anyway
* Having a second line, with a transparent (0 opacity) set of line segments where it should be - they aren't visible and have no effect (who'd have thunk it?)
* Drawing each line segment individually - my computer has just about come back down to room temperature after trying to render 20,000 line segments, and then rendering another 20,000 after a modification (40,000 total!) and performance came down to a crawl. Not desired results.

I was hoping that `THREE.Geometry` and `THREE.Line` had some sort of functionality for removing specific line segments from a line, but does it?

---

PS. Should it not, and it is confirmed, I will probably do the work of moving this over into `THREE.BufferGeometry` and using shaders to render certain lines as invisible. Might just take a while and was hoping to avoid going that far.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think I could help you if I would fully understand your issue. Why do you add these vertices in the first place? Can you not just skip adding them to the geometry in the first place?

Comment: @Wilt: Apologies if it was unclear - I add the vertices to a `THREE.Geometry` object because until then, it's just an array I built with X Y Z information. Unless there's a better way to draw a line and/or something else?

Comment: That part I understand. But some other part I don't: you add some points to the geometry for your line that you want to remove again, right? But why not skip adding them in the first place? I don't see where your problem is...

Comment: @Wilt: I've found that even not adding them to the geometry and using that geometry will still draw the lines between them. But now it would just use the points before and after the points I removed.

Comment: What version of three.js are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of drawing a line with a geometry in three.js.

1. A continuous line : [`THREE.Line( geometry, material );`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Objects/Line)
2. A segmented line : [`THREE.LineSegments( geometry, material );`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Objects/LineSegments)

### THREE.LineSegments

The `THREE.LineSegments` class connects **every two subsequent vertices** with a line. So if you want a continuous line with this class you would need to duplicate the points in the middle.

To explain it here an example:

```
v1 = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
v2 = new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 );
v3 = new THREE.Vector3( 20, 0, 0 );
v4 = new THREE.Vector3( 30, 0, 0 );
```

If you make a geometry using these points and use `THREE.LineSegments`:

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push( v1, v2, v3, v4 );

line = new THREE.LineSegments( geometry );
```

It will look like this:

```
.__.  .__.
1  2  3  4
```

If you do :

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push( v1, v2, v2, v3, v3, v4 );

line = new THREE.LineSegments( geometry );
```

it will look like this:

```
.__.__.__.
1  2  3  4
```

---

### THREE.Line

The `THREE.Line` class behaves differently and will **always connect all vertices** with a continuous line.

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push( v1, v2, v3, v4 );

line = new THREE.Line( geometry );
```

Will draw a continuous line connecting the points from the vertices array:

```
.__.__.__.
1  2  3  4
```

I hope this will help you solve your issue.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the answer. I am going to try this out, and I'm pretty sure this is it, but clarifying: I should add _pairs of vertices_ into my geometry and use `THREE.LineSegments` to join all of those pairs?

Comment: @JonLim Exactly like that!

Comment: Worked beautifully! I will have to make some more adjustments to my code, otherwise this is fantastic. Thank you so much!